# yii2 how to send mail in the background

Tags: yii2

I've done all kinds of searching on this topic and there seems to be many approaches to sending email after a user event.  For example, registering an account.  I don't like  sending it as part of the submit page because it tends to take a few seconds.  In the past, I've just set up a cron to run every 10 minutes or so and then trigger a script to check if mail needs to be sent.  This works, but it seems like such a waste of resources to have it checking every 10 minutes.

My question is... is there a way to trigger the mail to be sent immediately after the page is submitted, but not during the processing of that page?  In other words, have the page pass control to another script once it is complete.  I don't think this is possible with PHP, but thought I would ask.

I'm using MySQL and thought it might be possible using database triggers once a record is created, but not very familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

@hoang you can achieve this using cronjob. Once your pre-logic or data saved then you can manage flag for execute cronjob.

you can create cronjob in Console => Controller, and you can execute manually cron job like In cmd just write below command.

Php yii /.

OR you can set in your server also.

Answer (score -1):

With Yii 1 I'm using yii-resque.
example for yii1: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-resque/

Maybe it good for yii 2.0
Flow: Browser => submit => save data => call Resque Job (this job run in background) => Done.
User doesn't need wait.

For Yii2 you can use yii2-resque: https://github.com/sprytechies/yii2-resque

Comment: This is exactly what @hoangk is trying to avoid. yii2-resque relies on polling. It does not execute anything immediately.